# Problemas al ejecutar composer update o install

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer, instalacion

Estoy bajando un proyecto y al ejecutar composer update o install me sale un error en

Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout "https://***:***@github.com/rtconner/laravel-kint.git.git"

¿Alguna idea? busqué ese repo en github pero ya no existe, sin embargo no sé porqué la toma.

Algunos compañeros hacen lo mismo y no les sale error y tenemos todo igual.

Tengo instalada la versión de composer Composer version 1.10.5

Corriendo en mi máquina php 7.2

Adjunto la información del composer.json

Agradezco mucho de antemano.

----- Contenido composer.json----

```html
{
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "0.8.6",
    "chumper/zipper": "^1.0",
    "ddeboer/imap": "^0.5.2",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2",
    "kint-php/kint": "^1.1",
    "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.3.0",
    "league/csv": "8.2.1",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "2.1.27",
    "nesbot/carbon": "^1.22",
    "orangehill/iseed": "^2.5",
    "pusher/pusher-php-server": "~2.6",
    "rtconner/laravel-kint": "~2.0",
    "soundasleep/html2text": "~0.5",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "1.0.0-beta.3",
    "zizaco/entrust": "*"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7",
    "xethron/migrations-generator": "^2.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/",
      "Inggema\\Core\\": "app/Packages/Inggema/Core/src/",
      "Inggema\\CRMAllus\\": "app/Packages/Inggema/crm-allus/src/",
      "Inggema\\LindeBulk\\": "app/Packages/Inggema/linde-bulk/src/",
      "Inggema\\LindeEmail\\": "app/Packages/Inggema/linde-email/src/",
      "Inggema\\LindeRemeo\\": "app/Packages/Inggema/linde-remeo/src/",
      "Inggema\\LindeNotascd\\": "app/Packages/Inggema/linde-notascd/src/",
      "Inggema\\LindeOrders\\":"app/Packages/Inggema/linde-orders/src/",
      "Inggema\\LindeHIQ\\": "app/Packages/Inggema/linde-hiq/src/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
      "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
      "php artisan optimize"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿dicho paquete está o estaba en composer.json? ¿es una dependencia de otro paquete? falta un poco de información.

Comment: Sí en el composer.json se encuentra, lo raro es que otro compañero hace un composer update o install y no le sale el error, y el composer.json está igual

Comment: Agrega el contenido de composer.json a la pregunta

Comment: Listo Shaz, agregado

Comment: ¿tal vez los compañeros tienen dicho paquete en el caché de composer?